# Root Category and Sub Categories are not showing in the Admin Panel

Tags: category, admin

I recently installed Magento Community 1.7 and a template on my site.
The menu appears fine on the site, but in the Admin panel, I don't see any Root Category or Sub Categories. 
I've tried reindexing the data but still no luck?
It looks just like this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following blog post.

https://samumaretiya.wordpress.com/2016/04/23/category-tree-not-showing-on-admins-product-edit-page/

I hope you will find your solution from there.